# The Query does not execute Properly

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008

I have the code for calling a query from 2 databases but it has to compile at the same time. Here is my code

```
public void SummTEkspor(){
        TEkspor ti = new TEkspor();
        TEksporDAOImpl impd = new TEksporDAOImpl (DBConnection.getInstance().getCon());
        String sql1 ="DELETE FROM a.dbo.t_export\n" +
                     "INSERT INTO a.dbo.t_export\n" +
                     "SELECT * FROM b.dbo.export x WHERE x.sk_batch IN \n" +
                     "(SELECT sk_batch from batch_hdr WHERE 

                          mth="+cmbBln.getSelectedItem()+
                         "AND year="+cmbThn.getSelectedItem();


        try {
            Statement st = kon.conn.createStatement();
            Statement st2 = kon.secCon.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql1);
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("success");
            }
        } catch (Exception x) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
```

But, when i run it, the output is fine, but the query does not execute properly which there is no data inside my table whereas there are some data will be on that table.

Is there any solution to solve that? Thanks for any reply

Comment: what is a `delete from insert into` query? Especially if it's the same table

Comment: I need refresh the data from that table as the time is selected from combobox. That is the reason why i didn't choose `executeUpdate` instead of `executeQuery`. Is there any other solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using `executeUpdate` instead of `executeQuery` to do the data update. Separate the select query and execute it using `executeQuery` and get the resultset.

Comment: if executeUpdate is used then how can OP call resultset

Comment: @javaBeginner updated the answer. Thanks for picking it, i just wrote the answer for helping to insert the data.

Comment: i tried just like your suggestion, but i really confused because it didn't run the query (in try). I said that because it only shows `Error`. Did i miss something there?

Comment: That error is from Catch exception, which i put `System.out.println("error");` . I modify again, where i put a `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(cmbThn, x);` but the error `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserverexception : the statement did not return the result set`. If it's possible for me to know, what's a problem happened in this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `executeUpdate` instead of `executeQuery` and try divide your query into several queries.

Answer (score 0):

The better alternative would be not to using all statements in a single line because for retrieving you should call executequery and for deleting or inserting you call executeUpdate methods.
Also avoid using `statement` and use `PreparedStatement`

Comment: i tried just like your suggestion, but i really confused because it didn't run the query (in try). I said that because it only shows `Error`. Did i miss something there?

Comment: That error is from Catch exception, which i put `System.out.println("error");` . I modify again, where i put a `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(cmbThn, x);` but the error `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserverexception : the statement did not return the result set`. If it's possible for me to know, what's a problem happened in this?

Comment: @syaloom i could not undertstand.Well in catch block write x.printstacktrace and update the question with errors and point out the line numbe also where you get error